# angular.js prevent empty number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to force input number with required attribute to have always some value and on empty to have zero.
`<input ng-model='someModel' required>`
I had created the next directive:

```
App.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if ($attrs.type == 'number') {
                if ($element[0].required) {
                    $element.on('blur', function(){
                        if(this.value===''){
                            this.value=0;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I know that using this.value is wrong because it changes the value and not the scope. but I don't know how to change the scope itself.
`$scope.value` is not working at all.
I want this directive to be generic as possible so I don't want to specify in the scope the model name.

Comment: I dont think you shouldn't use a directive for this, you can break this down further and move it into a service. You could have say a service dedicated to handling validation rules and this would be one particular portion that you could use whenever you want. Inject something like... ValidationService.enforceFloatingZero($scope.var). If you need I could provide code to show this (the one below does not use a service but the simple function resides inside the controller).. you do not really want a directive for this unless you want ALL inputs with type number to behave like this or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach.

```
App.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.type === 'number' && attrs.required) {

                function update() {
                  if (!scope[attrs.ngModel]) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                      scope[attrs.ngModel] = 0;
                    });
                  }
                }

                element.on('blur', update)

                // remove listener when scope is destroyed
                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                  element.off('blur', update)
                })

            }
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4yDTNUfdpu2ql1EmTZ3B?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use `isNaN(parseInt(''))` as I think it is more explicit than the exact equals. Both would work for sure, but it is not immediately clear that you are checking for a lack of entry.

This solution looks messy to me as well, but it is a step in the right direction. Maybe someone with a bit more experience could look at it.

```
App.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            if ($attrs.type == 'number') {
                if ($element[0].required) {
                    $element.on('blur', function(){
                        if(isNaN(parseInt(ngModel.$viewValue))){
                            scope.$apply(function(){
                              ngModel.$viewValue = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The AngualarJS:

```
var replaceWithZeros = (function(angular) {
  "use strict";
  var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
  demo.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someModel = '0.00';
    $scope.someFunction = function(curVal) {
      if (!curVal) {
        $scope.someModel = '0.00';
      }
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

The HTML:

```
<main ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoCtrl">  
  <input ng-model="someModel" ng-blur="someFunction(someModel)" required="required"/>
</main>
```

Heres the demo to show it all working together, the markup is in HTML above however it is in jade in the demo hope that doesn't cause you any confusion.

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/xGPvJd